# Generate set/get methods for a c++ class

Tags: c++, class, methods, get, set

Is there any tool that generates set and get methods for a class automatically.

Just I create classes very frequently and would like to have a tool which for each class-member wil generate the following functions automatically:

```
Member_Type getMemberName() const; //in header file
Member_Type getMemberName() const //in source file 
{
    return member;
}

void setMemberName(const Member_Type & val); //in header
void setMemberName(const Member_Type & val) //in source file 
{
    member = val;
}
```

I have met a macro like this but did not like the idea:

```
#define GETSETVAR(type, name) \
private: \
    type name; \
public: \
    const type& get##name##() const { return name; } \
    void set##name##(const type& newval) { name = newval; }
```

May be someone knows how to do that with MS Visual Studio, or eny other tool?

Comment: If you want all of your members to be publically modifiable (and if you do your classes aren't providing any abstraction) why not just make them public? A `struct` does this by default.

Comment: Many of the answers to the following question are relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977007/public-data-members-vs-getters-setters/2977040#2977040. Bottom line: you may think you want this, but it's generally a terrible idea.

Comment: That is out of OOP (this is a formal reason) and may be I want to add some checks in set-functions (for example), then I should have set/get functions.

Comment: I'd be surprised if IDEs don't allow for that. NetBeans for Java for example allows me to create setters and getters with a right-click. I've got MS Visual Studio 08 on a different PC and can't check right now - does anybody know by chance if any major IDE for C++ has that feature?

Comment: @Narek: If OOP practice requires you to do something dumb then perhaps OOP is not the way to go? OOP is a means to an end, not a goal in itself. The goal should always be good, clean code. You don't get that by quadrupling your code size and writting getters/setters for *everything*. (Apart from this, it is often not good OOP practice either to do this. The class should expose the logical operations that make sense on the class. get/set are not usually meaningful operations, they're just shortcuts to modifying the internals of the class.

Comment: @jalf: I am sure you understand the word "formal" quite well, but anyway thanks for "good code" characteristics. Hoped you could answer my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "formal" in this context? When you say "that is out of OOP" do you mean that not having getters and setters is outside the bounds or limits of OOP? I just want to make sure that I completely understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Narek: A class full of getters and setters is the antithesis of OO.

Comment: FredOverflow: What is OOP? What is incapsulation?

Comment: What editor or IDE are you using?

Comment: Qt Creator doesn't seem to have advanced editing features, but it allows you to invoke external editors. Are you familiar with another editor, like vi or emacs?

Comment: May be someone knows how to do that with MS Visual Studio?

Comment: You asked for a better solution:  DON'T DO THAT!  Implement functions that make sense based on what the class is and represents, and what the class invariants are.  Automatically producing getters and setters exposes the internal implementation, violating encapsulation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not the tool actually, but you could use `Encapsulate Method` in *Visual Assist X*, for example, which makes *getter / setter* methods for some private class member.

*Sure, many of tools that work similiar as VAX do have the same methods.*

Also, if you have to do this action for a huge amount of classes, you could implement your own command-line tool and lauch it for every source file that you have.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to be generating these methods?

Generally a better approach is to make an actual use interface that defines operations on the object, not just sets of individual attributes. By creating a class interface, you avoid the need to write a bunch of getters and setters.

If you really need to generate public getters and setters for all (or even most) of your attributes, probably better is to just make it a struct, then no such generation is needed.

Comment: and the `struct` should be public within the class?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Visual Studio, my [Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) add-in will do this - it will instantly add getter/setter methods for a member field, using a naming style of your choice.

e.g. if you have this:

```
public:

   ...

private:
    int m_Speed;
```

Then you can execute the command to convert it to this

```
public:
    // Access the Speed
    int GetSpeed(void) const    { return(m_Speed);  };
    void SetSpeed(int speed)    { m_Speed = speed;  };

    ...

private:
    int m_Speed;
```

*(Note: you don't have to use "m_" or "Get..." - this is just an example to show how it handles prefixed or suffixed naming schemes. You can configure the member naming style used (speed, _speed, mSpeed, m_speed, etc) and the naming style for the getter/setter methods (GetSpeed(), get_speed(), etc))*

---

It does similar things when applied to a C# member:

```
protected int m_Speed;
```

then you can execute the command to convert it to an auto property:

```
protected int Speed { get; set; }
```

...and execute the command a second time to produce a property with a backing field:

```
protected int Speed
{
    get { return(m_Speed); }
    set { m_Speed = value; }
}
private int m_Speed;
```

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Kotti - Visual Assist (and other addins) provide this functionality.

The actual source code should have the getters / setters, because you probably want to add validation and change notification to the setters as needed.

Using a macro for that is just... facepunchable. (willing to elaborate on request).

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a tool so I wrote a python script in 10 minutes. Its not perfect but its helpful:

generate_getters.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 1:
    print 'usage: > python script.py <cpp_file_name>'

fileName = sys.argv[1]
className = fileName.split('.')[-2].split("/")[-1]

print 'classname:' +  className

def printGetterSettersForLine(line):
    syntax = line.strip().split(';')[0]
    words = syntax.split()
    if len(words) != 2:
        return
    getter = words[0] + ' ' + className + '::get' + words[1].title() + '() { \n'
    getter = getter + '     return ' + words[1] + ';\n'
    getter = getter + '}';
    print getter

with open(fileName) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            printGetterSettersForLine(line)
```

Usage: > python generate_getters.py ClassName.h
Generating setter is left as exercise for reader. ;)