# Accessing member variables with getters C++

Tags: c++, pointers, getter

If I have this private map of scenes in my header file

```
std::map<std::string, Scene> scenes;
```

Should my public getter be like so?

```
std::map<std::string, Scene>* getScenes() { return &scenes; }
```

Still getting my head around pointers in c++ so apologies if it seems like a dumb question

Comment: Assuming all of this is actually members in some unstated class, probability is high that you don't need a pointer in the first place; a reference will do, and *maybe* even a value-return, depending on unstated purpose of providing a getter in the first place. Also, consider whether `getScenes` should be `const`, because chances are it can be. Finally, consider whether the resulting reference can/should also be `const`, again, depending on the purpose of providing that getter.

Comment: Why do you need a pointer here? Returning a plain pointer to a private member kind of defeats the whole purpose of making the member private. If you want it to be accessed by non-members it shouldn't be private in the first place. It's more likely that your getter should return something like a const reference or even a single element in the map depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need to, returning a pointer to a member that isn't stored as a pointer isn't a great idea. Passing pointers around can get messy e.g. if the original object goes out of scope you'll end up with a dangling pointer. Returning by const reference should be your first port of call:

```
const std::map<std::string, Scene>& getScenes() const { return scenes; }
```

This will avoid a copy while preserving const correctness. This obviously isn't a one size fits all approach, but quite often if you want a getter for a non-primitive type, you will want to return by const reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pointer is rarely a good idea, considering you can return by reference.

```
std::map<std::string, Scene>& getScenes() { return scenes; }
```

This however is also not very good and defeats the purpose of making the member variable private, as does returning a pointer to it.

To access the member variable to view the data and not change it, which lends some sense to having a getter of a private member variable, you should return a const reference:

```
const std::map<std::string, Scene>& getScenes() const { return scenes; }
```

I'll just add that some defend that getters and setters [are just clutter and you shoud just go ahead and make the member variable public](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2977019/6865932) if need be.

Others defend [that it should be used with parsimony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32625641/6865932).

Others still, [that they sholud be used but only because they're the lesser o two evils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2977045/6865932).

Comment: returning a non-const refrence is rarely a good idea. It compeltely defeats the purpose of making the member private. If you return a non-const reference then the getter is really just clutter and of no real use

Comment: @idclev463035818, yes, I agree, since the OP has a simple pointer to the member I started with that simple change, I added some clarity to my answer.